# Why might I be unable to create an instance of System.Windows.Forms.Form in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an intermittent problem where I cannot create an instance of the System.Windows.Forms.Form class in my C# library. I log exceptions in my program, but unfortunately nothing was recorded for this problem. It might not be relevant, but my library, called via COM (i.e. there is no Main method).

So I threw a test exception, and it was caught and logged successfully -- so I'm thinking that maybe something screwy is going on in the message loop?

#### Update 1

The Form is created using the following code in a `Thread` which has `ApartmentState.STA` set.

```
  someForm = new Form();
  someForm.Visible = false;
  someForm.Text = "Hello world!";
```

Comment: maybe some code will shine some light on the problem

Comment: Hmm, the code is so massive and complex, the only thing I could provide is pseudo code which might not be so useful. I will update my question to be less vague.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a guess, since you've provided no code and little context, but might you be missing the `STAThread` attribute on your entry point method (`Main`)? This is necessary for WinForms apps that make use of COM.

Comment: Ah, actually the entry point is not via Main, it is via a COM call. Have you ever seen `someForm = new Form();` throw an exception?

Comment: I hope this is the right answer! I love it when people take a shot in the dark and hit!

Comment: @Iain: Heh, I hope so too. It's a game, really - might just get lucky! It's the first possible solution that came to mind from experience though.

Comment: Noldorin: I have looked in to the code a little more and it seems that the thread in which I am creating the `Form` does indeed have  `ApartmentState.STA` passed to it's `SetApartmentState` method. So I think that in this case lack of STA is not the issue. Any other ideas why I am unable to create an instance of `Form`? Memory issues perhaps?

Comment: @nbolton: Ok, glad you checked that at least. No other thoughts at the moment, sorry, will let you know if I do.

Comment: Noldorin: Thanks -- hmm, maybe someone could suggest a way of causing `new Form()` to throw an exception? Though, it may still be one of the other two lines which set the `Visible` and `Text` properties.